# strpos in foreach is only checking the last array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, strpos

I made a simple program for checking weather a string is contain in a variable or not with strpos but when I am checking this I found that it is only checking the last array.

Here is my php

```
$branda = $_GET['brand'];
$brandq = $row['company'];
$my3 = array($brandq);

foreach($my3 as $map){
    $mane=strpos($branda,$map);

    if($mane !== false)
    {
        $myfunction2 = "'".str_replace(",","','",$branda)."'";
        $condition2='and product.company IN('.$myfunction2.') ';
    } else {
        $condition2='';
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the contents of `var_dump($row['company'])` ?

Comment: you put 
`$my3 = array($brandq);`
so foreach iterate throught array of size 1

Comment: I found the solution for this. What i have done is i have replaced `$mane=strpos($branda,$map);` it with this `$mane=$mane.strpos($branda,$map);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made some assumptions:

```
// Assumptions
$row['company'] = array("apple","samsung","microsoft","sony");
$_GET['brand']  = "microsoft";

This code should be correct:

$branda = $_GET['brand'];
$brandq = $row['company'];
$condition2 = "";

foreach ($brandq as $map) {
    $mane = strpos($branda,$map);

    if ($mane !== false) {
        $myfunction2 = "'".str_replace(",","','",$branda)."'";
        $condition2 .='and product.company IN('.$myfunction2.') ';
    }
}
```

Echo out the result:

```
echo $condition2 . PHP_EOL;

Output: and product.company IN('microsoft')
```

Answer (score 0):

I have made some assumptions:

```
// Assumptions
$row['company'] = array("apple","samsung","microsoft","sony");
$_GET['brand']  = "microsoft";
```

This code should be correct:

```
$branda = $_GET['brand'];
$brandq = $row['company'];
$condition2 = "";

foreach ($brandq as $map) {
    $mane = strpos($branda,$map);

    if ($mane !== false) {
        $myfunction2 = "'".str_replace(",","','",$branda)."'";
        $condition2 .='and product.company IN('.$myfunction2.') ';
    }
}
```

Echo out the result:

```
echo $condition2 . PHP_EOL;
```

Output: `and product.company IN('microsoft')`